# AWS Pinpoint: How to get notification when app install/run directly from Xcode into device?

Tags: swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

We have created project in Mobile Hub and manage AWS Pinpoint to send push notification in iOS devices and setup AWS Pinpoint console for push notification. We have uploaded development certificate .p12 and download the demo app from our application(project) which is created using 'AWS Mobile Hub' web service(Screen shot attached). We are getting notification while installing it from adhoc IPA. But, We are unable to get notification when we are installing directly from Xcode into my device. 
So, how to get notification when app install/run directly from Xcode ?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Previously, the Pinpoint console didn't support sending push notifications via the APNs Sandbox development environment.

**Note:** This feature was supported earlier only by invoking the API (not through the console). You can make a call to the API to do the following:

1. To register the APNs Sandbox Channel.
2. Register a device as an APNs Sandbox endpoint.
3. Send messages/campaign pushes to it.

As of yesterday (10/03/2017) Pinpoint fully supports APNs Sandbox environment through the console as well. In order to register a device as an APNs Sandbox endpoint, use the latest version of the AWS iOS SDK (v2.6.2 or above) and enable the debug flag. This corresponds to the Sandbox development environment. 
You can enable the debug flag by using the following code snippet

```
AWSPinpointConfiguration *config = [AWSPinpointConfiguration defaultPinpointConfigurationWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
[config setDebug:YES];
AWSPinpoint *_pinpoint = [AWSPinpoint pinpointWithConfiguration:config];
```

Comment: How do I make this configuration? In the àppDelefate`?

Comment: Yes, its in the app delegate.